# Firebase or firebase+paypal paid only accounts

Tags: firebase, paypal

I'm trying to set up user accounts for my website which are paid only. I don't want a user to have an option to create an account without having already paid. How would I go about this?

Example:

- google pay button with a click subscribe simultaneously adding them on a subscription and creating their account (not sure how I would do this integration)
- Paypal subscribe button which then takes them to a page where they can sign up after they pay (not sure how I would get their paypal subscription information though on that response if they don't choose to sign up)
- I did find paypal subscriptions that generate usernames and passwords (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/user-names-passwords/), however I dont know how I would correlate this with my firebase users.

I'd prefer a solution where after they subscribe they are automatically added to google firebase with an email and password (or temp password) and their paypal ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use firebase functions and require they initiate a subscription with paypal buttons and onApprove of the paypal buttons, send an API call to your google function to add them to the database and send the sign up email.